# Iterated Function System Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to learn more about set-theory, specifically in application to the [iterated function system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) (IFS). Would you please explain the following set formula in English:

$\{f_i : X \rightarrow X | i = 1, 2, ..., N\}, N \in \mathbb{N}$

I understand $X$ is a set, but to the right of the arrow, does this mean it implies a *new* set $X$ is dependent on $i$ (how does this work?)? I am also confused about $f_i$ - how is the function dependent on $i$?

If you could recommend some reading material, please do.

Thanks.

Comment: The notation $f_i:X\to X$ simply means that $f_i$ is a function defined on $X$ and taking values on (the same) $X$. (There is no "new" $X$.) That we have $f_i$ for $1,\dots,N$ simply means that we have $N$ functions. The set $\{f_i:X\to X\mid i=1,2,\dots,N\}$ is therefore a set consisting of $N$ functions, each of them from $X$ to itself. For example, say $X=\mathbb R$, $N=2$, $f_1:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the function $\displaystyle f_1(x)=\frac x3$, and $f_2:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac x3+\frac23$. (This system is related to the Cantor set.)

Comment: Now, note that there are additional requirements, as mentioned at the link: $X$ is not just an arbitrary set, but rather a complete metric space, and each $f_i$ must be a contraction.

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with set theory. It is a good starting point for the theory of fractals, though.

Comment: Would the third function be: $f_3(x) = \frac{x}{3} + \left( \frac{2}{3} + \frac{\frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3}}{3}\right)$?

Comment: @Biff Not necessarily. The *only* requirement for $f_3$ is that it be a function mapping $X$ to itself.

Comment: @Dan Christensen Understood. However, if the set were to fulfill the requirements of the Cantor set, would that be $f_3(x)$?

Comment: There is no $f_3$ in my example. I even said that $N=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{f_i : X \rightarrow X | i = 1, 2, ..., N\}, N \in \mathbb{N}$ is just a set of $N$ functions, namely the functions $f_1, f_2, ... , f_N$. And each one of them maps $X$ to itself.

Comment: The only implicit assumption is that $f(x)$ is somehow *defined* and that, as you said, each one maps $X$ to itself?

Comment: @Biff There is no $f(x)$ here. The subscripts are part of the names of each of the $N$ functions. Instead, you would have $f_1(x)$ or $f_2(x)$, etc.

Comment: You would have to provide a starting function though, correct? In other words, it would always be $f_1(x)$.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "starting function." $f_2$ isn't somehow dependent on or determined by $f_1$. We are not talking about recursively defined functions here.

Comment: Oh, I see. If it were to be a fractal, however, would that be the case?

Comment: Don't get confused. This has nothing to do with fractals.

Comment: I do realize that the functions could be completely arbitrary, but I was interested in distinguishing how IFSs are used with fractals.

Comment: @Biff The connection with fractals is probably too subtle for you to fully understand right now: If $X$ is a complete metric space, and all the $f_i$ are contractions, we can define a map $F$ on the space $K(X)$ of compact subsets of $X$, endowed with the Hausdorff metric, by setting $F(C)=\bigcup_{i\le N}f_i(C)$ for each nonempty compact set $C\subseteq X$. It happens that $F:K(X)\to K(X)$ is again a contraction, so by a theorem of Banach it has a unique fixed point, which is a compact set (a subset of $X$). This set is what we would call the fractal associated with the IFS you began with.